# How can I get a pointer to the first element in an std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to write data from an `std::vector<char>` to a socket, using the `write` function, which has this prototype:

```
ssize_t write(int, const void *, size_t);
```

The second argument to this function must be a pointer to the first element in the `std::vector<char>`. How can I get a pointer to this element?

I tried `std::vector::front` but this returns a reference, while I need a pointer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
&mv_vec[0]
```

or

```
&my_vec.front()
```

Comment: .data() (C++11) should be preferred. mv_vec[0] does not work if array is empty.

Comment: @TarmoPikaro You still need to check the size. You cannot dereference the result of `std::vector::data` if `std::vector::size` is zero. `std::vector::data` is preferred because if the vector is empty, it does not result in undefined behavior like `&v[0]` does.

Comment: I would prefer not to check anything. So you should get some dummy pointer, but if size() is 0, there is nothing done with that dummy pointer. Will front() work like this ? At least for release builds ?

Comment: @TarmoPikaro - I imagine the point is that you're presumably obtaining that pointer because you intend to do something with it at some point.  Therefore you're always going to need to do a check.

Comment: You're correct, but if you do something in for loop, then if i'm lazy - I dont want to do extra check for zero size vector.

Comment: I get "error: taking address of temporary" when I do this. Which is weird, because I swear it usually works. I am in a template function, would that make a difference? I get the same error with the .data() function. Or is it because am using the template parameter for the vector type? e.g. std::vector<T>?

Comment: Actually I remembered wrong, the error is different with .data(), I get "error: void value not ignored as it ought to be". I am assigning the result to a void pointer, but usually that works too... (void* buffer = myvector.data();)

Comment: Ahh, ok, it is because one of the template instantiations is T=bool, and the std::vector<bool> specialisation is apparently kind of bizarre and doesn't work like the rest of vectors. No idea if it is fixable though. Well anyway it looks like this *doesn't* work for vectors of bools.

Comment: Both `&my_vec[0]` and `&my_vec.front()` produce UB for empty vector. In this regard `data()` is better, since it allows for one less logical operation. Easier to write, easier to read.

Answer (score 82):

C++11 has `vec.data()` which has the benefit that the call is valid even if the vector is empty.

Comment: +1 for reminding me to check if the vector is empty. I'm writing software in C++03, unfortunately.

Comment: This is the right answer. If you write someFunc(my_vec.size(), &my_vec[0]) then you have undefined behavior. Ditto for pretty much every answer here. You cannot dereference .begin() on an empty vector and .front() is not defined on an empty vector. Only someFunc(my_vec.size(), my_vec.data()) is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 6):

```
my_vec.empty() ? 0 : &my_vec.front()
```

If you would like an `std::out_of_range` to be thrown if vector is empty, you could use

```
&my_vec.at(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
&*my_vec.begin()
```

or

```
&mv_vec[0]
```

Comment: `my_vec.front()` is a less cumbersome version of `*my_vec.begin()`.

Answer (score 1):

By taking the address of the first element, with `&vec[0]`, as the standard (since C++03, I think) demands continous storage of `std::vector` elements.

Comment: This results in undefined behavior if the vector is empty.